# What should I include in my PhD interview Presentation?

Tags: phd, interview, presentation

So I have been shortlisted for a PhD scholarship and I have an interview next week.I have been asked to give a 5-minute presentation titled: "A short introduction of my profile and how this fits with the proposed PhD position."

I am a bit confused as everything that I have been searching on in terms of examples for the presentation focuses on research and results and I am not sure if I should focus on that in my presentation, given the proposed title. I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You should talk about what you've done in research (your profile) and tie it specifically to the PhD position you are applying for (how this fits with the proposed PhD position).

So, if you're applying for a PhD position in an underwater basket weaving lab, your presentation should focus on whichever elements apply to your background: have you've weaved before? have you worked underwater? If you haven't weaved baskets, do you at least have experience transporting things in baskets?

You want someone watching your presentation to see how you will be successful in the role based on what you've done before. 5 minutes is very short. Don't waste time with empty promises or things that anyone could say. Focus on concrete things that are special about what you've accomplished. It's okay if those accomplishments are not entirely successful: if all you've done is show conclusively that a particular weave won't work that's still very useful background because research is all about getting it wrong before you get it right.